# Enviar e-mail com Laravel 4.2 não chega aos destinatários

Tags: php, envio-de-email, laravel-4, gmail

Olá,

estou tentando enviar e-mails utilizando o **Laravel 4.2** porém as mensagens só chegam quando o e-mail do destinatário é o mesmo de que esta enviando.
A configuração do arquivo **mail.php** ficou assim:

```
<?php

return array(


    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => 'testes@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Teste com Emails'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'testes@gmail.com',
    'password' => '1234567890',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

);
```

O código utilizado para enviar e-mails ficou assim:

```
\Mail::send('emails.hello', array('key' => 'value'), function($message)
            {
                $message->to('testes@gmail.com', 'Leandro');
                $message->from('testes@gmail.com', 'Testes');
                $message->subject('Welcome!');
            });
```

Um detalhe que talvez seja importante, estou trabalhando em um ambiente de desenvolvimento, localhost, para a aplicação.

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Comment: Você já verificou se o `e-mail` não está indo para a caixa de `spam` ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Existe [uma configuração nos e-mails enviados pelo gmail](http://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5) para liberar as configurações de restrição, por acaso já fez isso??? Eu tenho isso já implementado e envia e-mail para qualquer destinátario. [Leia o Link](http://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @JcSaint sim verifiquei, não esta caindo na caixa de spam. Vou editar a pergunta pois esqueci de colocar um detalhe que talvez seja importante, estou trabalhando em um ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic realmente precisava desbloquear o Gmail, fiz a alteração proposta e funcionou, muito obrigado.